# What type of curcuit breaker is this?

Tags: circuit-breaker

Anyone know what type of breaker this is? No description. Single pole 20 amp. House built in 70s.

[image]

Comment: what is printed on the side of the breaker in the small square area?

Comment: Was it in use before you removed it? What was hooked up to it?

Comment: I don't recognize it, but look for the name of the breaker box and any writing on the side of the breaker.  You typically use the same brand of breaker in the box to ensure UL compliance.

Comment: Eric is right.  You check the make of panel first and use breakers listed/named for that panel, NOT ones that also fit.

Comment: If somehow the name/labels of the panel are missing, take a picture of the whole panel and maybe someone on here will be able to tell you what breakers go with it.  Can edit your question or make a new one if you want.  Even if we knew that breaker, it might not belong in the the panel.

Comment: Looks to be the same as most of the others.

Answer (score 3):

That is probably an old style Cutler Hammer type CH Twin Plug-in Breaker. I say old style because the new ones have a molded plastic mounting clasp instead of a metal one.

Answer (score 3):

That is Cutler Hammer aka Eaton CH, the finest plug-on breaker ever offered in the consumer space. A competitor to Square D "QO".

Readily available in home stores.

The giveaway is the sandalwood handle and peculiar clip on the bus stab, which assures sufficient clamping pressure.

There's no need to change the panel unless you are out of breaker spaces or the panel is physically damaged or corroded.  There is nothing "electronic" or "capable of wear" in a bare panel. Mine are from the 1960s and going strong. Note that a new panel will be *much* larger, both due to changes in "wire bending space" rules, and CH/QO are 3/4" tall breakers, whereas others as 1" tall (making the breaker area 33% taller on anything that isn't CH or QO).

As far as the breakers, there have been refinements over the decades, and I couldn't fault you for replacing the breakers - the major difference is *all* new ones are SWD rated, which used to be a special order. SWD means rated to be used as a switch, interrupting full current every day, e.g. in warehouses and factories where the breaker *is* the light switch.

Eaton CH and Square D QO are not interchangeable.  (I mention that because some people think all 1" breakers are interchangeable, that's not true actually; their bus stabs differ enough to cause problems.)